# an exception occured - APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action. - BINANCE API

Tags: python, api, binance

Tengo el siguiente código pero a la hora de tratar de realizar una órden, me devuelve el error que he indicado en el título,

```
an exception occured - APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action.
```

¿alguien ha sufrido esto anteriormente? En gestión de API en Binance veo lo siguiente, no debería ser por tema de IP pues antes tenía activada la opción de que cualquier IP pudiera llamar a dicha API
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import websocket, json, pprint, talib, numpy
import config
from colorama import Fore
from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *

SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@kline_1m"


TRADE_SYMBOL = 'ETHUSD'
TRADE_QUANTITY = 0.01


client = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET, tld='us')

def order(side, quantity, symbol,order_type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET):
    try:
        print(Fore.GREEN + "sending order")
        order = client.create_order(symbol=symbol, side=side, type=order_type, quantity=quantity)
        print(order)
    except Exception as e:
        print("an exception occured - {}".format(e))
        return False

    return True

    
def on_open(ws):
    print(Fore.BLUE + 'opened connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')

def on_message(ws, message):
    print('received message')

    order_succeeded = order(SIDE_BUY, TRADE_QUANTITY, TRADE_SYMBOL)

                
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

El error se debía a la opción tld del Client, tenía 'us' cuando debía ser 'com' al ser una cuenta Binance de fuera de EEUU